# Laptop is too HOT with fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation

Tags: 16.04, temperature

I just made a new ubuntu 16 installation (from Linux mint) and following this [guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-switch-linux-distros-without-losing-files/) I made a new partition in which I saved my home folder.
Now it works but I get loads of errors at startup and the laptop is hotter than ever.

Yesterday I was installing docker and doing some extra stuff while waiting for the process to complete and the pc completely shut down. My guess is because the CPU temperature was too high. Also, note that my disk is an SDD.

Should I get my home folder back on the same partition as Ubuntu and stop mounting it at startup? Might be instead that I need to physically clean my device or is the crash happened because I stressed too much the machine or again is there something else I should look upon?

Thank you for any advice

**EDIT:**

**hdd temperature:**

sudo hddtemp /dev/sda1

```
/dev/sda1: KINGSTON SV300S37A240G: 41°C
```

**other temperatures:**

sensors

> nouveau-pci-0100 Adapter: PCI adapter GPU core:     +0.85 V  (min = 
>   +0.85 V, max =  +0.95 V) temp1:        +69.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
>                          (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
>                          (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
>
> coretemp-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter Core 0:       +61.0°C  (high =
>   +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C) Core 2:       +62.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

might be the temperatures are actually fine atm even if in touch it's very hot?

**EDIT 2:**

besides what sensors stated back there the pc is still burning hot, I tried using it with unplugged charger but no changes. After further research, I found out GPU drivers might be pertinent so I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers in place of nuveau

**EDIT 3:**

after failing to install stable Nvidia drivers I installed the missing package cpufrequtils and cleaned up my fan and temperature dropped by 10 degrees. I'm still stuck with nuveau for the GPU but at least I can use the laptop now.

**EDIT 4:**

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 420M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GF108M [GeForce GT 420M]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

Comment: How your partitions are distributed can theoretically not affect CPU usage and temperature. Also please include the "loads of errors at startup" into your question, we can't just guess what might be wrong.

Comment: I don't receive them anymore probably because i reported them checking the box to ignore further alerts on this error, can i still see them somewhere?

Comment: The HDD temperature is normal (at least for a 2.5 inch HDD, not sure about an SSD).

Comment: Core 0 and Core 2 temps are within normal boundaries compared to my laptop.

Comment: those data was with the PC in idle, with only 4 chrome tabs open went to 71/72 °C and when i try to install a driver (CPU goes to 100% usage) the pc shuts down (i guess) for overheating. Also it was far cooler before this installation when i was on mint

Comment: Nvidia drivers are not installed. That is the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Install Intel Power Clamp to prevent system shutting down. It slows the processor by inserting idle cycles to reduce overheating. This is a short term fix until you install TLP or another CPU frequency scaling and fan speed management package. I spent months perfecting my system and regret not keeping better notes for you and others.

Comment: I'll take a look at what 'TLP or other CPU frequency scaling packages' are

Comment: I ran into an issue because TLP defaults to performance mode when connected to AC power which was keeping my processor from frequency scaling. I changed it to powersave and now my CPU runs much cooler and scales up as necessary.